# how to install dotnet core on ubuntu 20.4?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu-20.04, dotnet-core-pack, dotnetcorecli

I'm trying to install Dotnet core on my server with this commands.

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb


sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

but the output of "dotnet --version"  is

```
It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
```

and when i went to root directory of my project and and use "sudo dotnet build -c Release"
the output is

```
      It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Does anyone have an idea?

=========update=========

I used Docker and all my problems were solved

Comment: through snap store

Comment: Cannot reproduce what you described above on a clean Docker image. So you have to troubleshoot further. BTW, try to learn and use Docker, as clean containers are most suitable for such scenarios to eliminate all kinds of system corruption.